# How to set/change default Download folder for Uget?

Tags: downloads, uget

Whenever I download with Uget, The Default Download folder is `$HOME` (for my case `/home/pandya`).

I know I can change download destination at time as follows:

[image: screen]

**But I want to change it permanently so-that I don't need to change every time.** 
**Where is setting or How to change?**

Comment: try to follow [this](http://ugetdm.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=787)

Comment: okey, I did not know I had to do in this case.

Comment: but yours is good enough, I think you accept it, and everything is ok :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the official documentation](http://ugetdm.com/documentation/tutorials/21-changing-the-default-download-locationfolder):

- **Open property by right-click on Home**

[image: screen1]

- **Change Folder location on Default for New Download**

[image: screen2]

Comment: not only the default download location can be changed in this way, but also the number of connections and other settings

Comment: I needed to relaunch my uGet for the new downloads to use the new location. I'm on Debian running uGet 2.0.8.

Answer (score 2):

Textual Walkthrough: (from [our documentation](http://ugetdm.com/documentation/tutorials/21-changing-the-default-download-locationfolder))

1. Right click the Home category in the uGet main window.
2. Select "Properties".
3. Click the 2nd tab at the top, "Default for new download 1".
4. Change this setting to whatever location/folder you want to be the default for this category.

This feature and tutorial is not limited to just the Home category...this can be done with as many categories as you want to make allowing you to easily switch between many different default settings and folders.

Visual for 1 and 2:
[image: Visual for #1 and #2]

Visual for 3 and 4:
[image]

Comment: why on earth would people downvote the official answer from an official project member?

Comment: visit [answer contains link only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92505) & [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84345)

Comment: That doesn't explain why because the link contains screenshots on the tutorial page. If it was a link to some random page for traffic padding then fine but it is the official answer from the official website. It doesn't make sense for it to be downvoted.

Comment: what do yo mean by "official answer"!?

Comment: Official Answer as in I am the project manager for uGet, I answered this question previously on our official website. The link I provided was to that page.

Comment: @Pandya - are you aware of the answer to your comment?

Comment: what's important is that the solution is posted, no matter that in other answer than yours

Comment: I am bothered purely for the negative vote count for providing the answer to the question. I wouldn't care if it was zero but for it to be negative for helping people with an application I manage is just irritating.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell The point is that whenever you update that website and break the link, which will probably happen, as has happened countless times for countless other things, this answer will become utterly useless, until such time that you update the link. The other answer will remain relevant barring changes to the software itself. The vote is negative because you failed to follow this site's standards. Would you accept poor code from a contributor?

Comment: @MichaelTunnell v2.2.0, I had to delete excess config-folders stacked up from usage by deleting lines from `~/.config/uGet/Setting.json` under `FolderHistory` albeit after closing uGet session ;-)